# Azure Logic App Custom Connector With Basic Auth

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-logic-apps

I have an external API. I connect to it with Postman via basic auth and all is well.

[image]

The blacked out part is the base64 encoded `username:password` combination.

I save this route as a Postman collection and that collection contains the following, relevant block:

```
"headerData": [
{
     "key": "Authorization",
     "value": "Basic <redacted>",
     "description": "",
     "enabled": true
}
```

At this point, I'm expecting that I will be able to upload the collection file to Azure and it will create me a custom connector that uses my username:password to authenticate.

But it does not:

[image]

Instead, Azure is aware that it will need to use basic auth, but it will not be using the credentials I supplied, nor will it allow me to enter credentials.

1) *How* would a user enter a valid username/password to use this connector?

2) I want this connector to work autonomously, without user intervention. Am I misunderstanding something?

EDIT:

It's apparently possible to provide the username/password via the logic app itself, but I am never prompted, nor is there anywhere to insert the information:

[image]

That's the custom connector there with `GETReservations`. Basic point still stands. I want this to be unattended, no user interaction (after initial setup, of course).

Answer (score 0):

The Basic authentication screen you have shown is just configuring the labels for username/password that will be displayed when you use the connector within a Logic App.

So if I understand your issue correctly, it should just be a matter of using that custom connector within a Logic App at which point you will be prompted for the username and password.

Comment: I was just looking into how I could supply the username/password to the logic app, but I'm not seeing how to do that, either. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You add the credential when you create the connection in the logic app. You have to create a new connection (click on change connection and make a new one).

This will create a new Api.

You can see you R25LogicAppCustomConnector as an API object in your resource group.